# AWS Batch Fargate memory pricing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate, aws-batch

I'm getting started to use AWS Batch, Fargate workload, and I want to know wheter when allocate memory quantity on job definition I'll be charged for all memory allocated or just for memory used. For example, on job definition I've allocated 4GB but my container execution used just 2GB, will I charged for 2GB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pricing is based on requested vCPU, memory, Operating Systems, CPU Architecture, and storage resources for the Task or Pod. You will pay for what you request when you start a container. You will pay for all the memory allocated to you.

You can estimate your costs using the price calculator:
https://calculator.aws/#/createCalculator/Fargate